# send base64 encoded image using curl

Tags: 14.04, command-line, curl

I am trying to send a base64 encoded image from the command line using `curl` and `base64` like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"image" : $( base64 ~/Pictures/1.jpg )}' http://some/url/
```

However, I get a response back saying that `$` is an unexpected token. How do I send the base64 encoded image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bash doesn't expand in single quotes. `'{"image" : $( base64 ~/Pictures/1.jpg )}'` gets sent as-is. Instead, try:

```
'{"image" : "'"$( base64 ~/Pictures/1.jpg)"'"}'
```

(Exit the opening quote before doing command substitution then open a quote again.)

Comment: You need to double-quote the `$()` else the base64 output lines will be split into several curl arguments.

Comment: Multiple images files and data command `$ curl -d "name=Avatar&username=avatar&password=A1234567&email=avatar@user.com&token=16b185fe421d5017afb11691681906ed" --data-urlencode 'avatar='"$( base64 ~/Pictures/avatar004.jpg)"'' --data-urlencode 'image='"$( base64 ~/Pictures/avatar001.jpg)"'' --data-urlencode 'picture='"$( base64 ~/Pictures/577383.jpg)"'' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/register/`

Answer (score 26):

@muru is correct, however 
if you are trying to send a *json* encoding your base64 data
may be too large for the command line and you may prefer something like this:

```
(echo -n '{"image": "'; base64 ~/Pictures/1.jpg; echo '"}') |
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @-  http://some/url/
```

The `-X POST` is implied by `-d`.

Comment: Yes, this much better.

Comment: Hi meuh, I failed when I try to run this combined command line from PHP code, $html = shell_exec($str);

if I copy $str code and run directly in command line, it's fine. But shell_exec did not work, please help :( thank you so much.

Comment: Haha, I created bash file, chmod +x that file, then write my command to file and run shell_exec('/path to sh file/xxx.sh');, I worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @BảoNam Ok, good solution. I don't much about php, and I don't see any obvious reason why the first version did not work. Look in the error log file of your server for clues. You would be better off starting a new question when php is involved, I think.